# 1 document with ~1000 objects in array or 1001 documents where 1 doc links to 1000 objects

Tags: couchdb

I'm still kind of having a problem with this.. I have a document that links to other smaller items. So my initial attempt was to create a 1 document that has some data along with 1000 results like this

```
{
    _id : 'testId',
    name : 'abe',
    results : [
        [1,5,'result', .... , 5, 'sec'],
        [2,4, 'pesult', ....., 'sec2']
        .
        .
        .
    ]
}
```

With this design, it seems cleaner since I could have like 1000 of these arrays in the results column, but now I have to paginate these results, so only return array items 50 to 100 or something

Should I be breaking up this document where each result is saved as a seperate document (and these documents would be very small)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on should your result set been consistent or not. E.g. if it's ok to miss one-two-dozen results from this 1000 set or to extend it with new ones: use one result per doc. Otherwise you better to keep them in single document.

Example life cases:

- many results per document: your documents represents test suite result, the group of tests where each has result passed/failed/error/skip etc. Depending on these values you may say if test suite passed or not. Test suite is consistent event for some point of time, so you won't have his state compromised by changing his tests results in future.
- one result per document: your documents represents single tests and result defines if it had been passed or not. There is no any strict suites or groups that keeps them within some consistent state.

But in anyway, to easy paginate things, use [recommended recipe](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/views/pagination.html) based on views.